# Non mahout java - implementation of Canopy clustering

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have my own java based implementation of clustering (knn). However I am facing scalability issues. I do not plan to use Mahout because my requirements are very simple and mahout requires lot of work. I am looking for java based Canopy clustering implementation which i can plug into my algo and do parellel processing.

Mahout based Canopy libraries are coupled with Vectors and indexes and does not work on plain strings. If you know of the way, where i can use canopy clustering on strings using simple library, it would fix my issue.

My requirement is to pass list of strings(say 10K) to Canopy clustering algo and it should return sublists based on T1 and T2.

Answer (score 2):

Canopy clustering is mostly useful as a preprocessing step for **parallelization**. I'm not sure how much it will get you on a single node. I figure you might as well compute the actual algorithm right away, or build an index such as an M-tree.

The strength of Canopy clustering is that you can run it *independently* on a number of nodes and then just overlap their results.

Also check if it actually is compatible to your approach. I figure that canopy might need *metric* properties to be correct. Is your string distance a proper metric (i.e. triangle inequality)?

Comment: The metric property has to hold for regular k-means as well, by the way

Comment: That is incorrect, k-means does not assume the triangle inequality. It assumes the *mean* is minimizing variances, which may not hold for other distances; k-means is written for Euclidean distance.

Comment: My mistake: what I meant to say was, I'd have the same concerns about the metric for k-means as for canopy, since I believe the canopy clustering simply approximates k-means by performing clusterings on sub-spaces of the original problem and merging them. Can you elaborate on what you mean by saying "the mean is minimising variances"? The cluster? means are minimising the variances of... what?

Answer (score 1):

10,000 data points, if that's all you're concerned with, should be no problem with standard k-means. I'd look at optimising that before you consider canopy clustering (which is really designed for millions or even billions of examples). Some things you may have missed:

- pre-compute the feature vectors for each string. Don't do it every time you want to compare s_1 to s_2 or s_1 to cluster centroid
- you only need to keep the summary statistics in memory: the sum of all points assigned to a cluster and the number of points assigned to a cluster. When you're done with an iteration, divides sums by ns and you have your new centroids.
- what's the dimensionality of your feature space? be aware that you should use a distance metric where the dimensions where both vectors are zero have no impact, so you should only need to compute for non-zero dimensions. Store your points as sparse vectors to facilitate this.

Can you do some analysis and determine where the bottle-neck in your implementation is? I'm a little perplexed by your comment about Mahout not working with plain strings.

Comment: 10,000 is just an example. I have data set of 2 GB strings and just one column.

Comment: I am little unclear about feature vectors because i have just plain strings like "Airport Parking" and "Airport parking systems". I believe Mahout vectors are kind of feature vectors. But I am not sure how strings got converted into number(if i open mahout vector file, it is numbers derived from lucene index file)

Comment: I donot have predetermined number of clusters, which i want to make. What i am doing is reading all the strings and using http://code.google.com/p/simile-vicino/source/browse/trunk/src/edu/mit/simile/vicino/clustering/NGramClusterer.java?r=2 class to cluster it. However it runs out of memory after 3-4 million records.

Comment: That code appears to be converting your strings to a bag of words/bag of n-grams anyway. Also, the implementation is using Collections to store the clusters and datapoints which, while good programming practice, isn't going to be memory efficient. Have a look at http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/ for an extremely efficient machine learning package in java which implements various clustering methods.

Comment: Thanks Ben, let me check out the mallet

Answer (score 1):

You should give the clustering algorithms in [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) a try. Sorry for so shamelessly promoting a project I'm closely affiliated with. But it is the largest collection of clustering and outlier detection algorithms that are implemented in a comparable fashion. (If you'd take all the clustering algorithms available in *some* R package, you might end up with more algorithms, but they won't be really comparable because of implementation differences)

And benchmarking showed enormous speed differences with different implementations of the same algorithm. See our [benchmarking](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Benchmarking) web site on how much performance can vary even on simple algorithms such as k-means.

We do **not yet have Canopy Clustering**. The reason is that it's more of a preprocessing index than actually a clustering algorithm. Kind of like a primitive variant of the M-tree, or of DBSCAN clustering. However, we should would like to see a contributed canopy clustering as such a preprocessing step.

ELKIs abilities to process strings are also a bit limited so far. You can load typical TF-IDF vectors just fine and we have somewhat optimized sparse vector classes and similarity functions. They don't fully exploit sparsity for k-means yet, though, and there is no spherical k-means yet either. But there are various reasons why k-means results on sparse vectors cannot be expected to be very meaningful; it's more of a heuristic.

But it would be interesting if you could give it a try for your problem and report back your experiences. Was the performance somewhat competitive with your implementation? And we would love to see contributed modules for text processing, such as e.g. further optimized similarity functions, or a spherical k-means variant.

**Update:** ELKI now actually **includes CanopyClustering**: [CanopyPreClustering](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/browser/elki/trunk/src/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/algorithm/clustering/CanopyPreClustering.java) (will be part of 0.6.0 then). But as of now, it's just another clustering algorithm, and not yet used to accelerate other algorithms such as k-means. I need to check how to best use it as some kind of index to accelerate algorithms. I can imagine it also helps for speeding up DBSCAN if you set T1=epsilon and T2=0.5*T1. The big issue with CanopyClustering IMHO is how to choose a good radius.